# AWS "No credentials specified" even when EC2 IAM policy applied

Tags: amazon-web-services

This is an odd issue which we can't find a solution for.

On AWS, we are running Microsoft Remote Desktop Services on Windows Server 2019.  All servers are joined to an AWS AD Directory Services domain.

The RDC Host Servers have an IAM policy that allows all actions to S3.

We have two users in the domain, both assigned to the same group - the default group "Domain Users".

When we log in to a Session Host with one user, we have no problem calling "Get-S3Object".  But when we log in with the second user and call "Get-S3Object", we get “No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults” - permissions should be given by the IAM policy attached to the EC2 which works for the first user.

To fix the problem, we have found that if we delete the second users' Windows profile, then the next time the second user logs in, they are given a TEMP profile and they are able to call "Get-S3Object", so clearly there is a problem with the user profile.

The Windows Servers are practically a vanilla instance and it's strange that deleting the User's profile fixes the issue...

We have also created a new domain user which had the same problem on one Session Host but not on another. It's a very random issue.

Has anyone else come across this problem?  What can be causing this to happen?

Comment: You could try checking if the instance metadata returns appropriate keys for each user. You would just curl to a URL as suggested by [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), but remember to substitute your own role name.

Comment: @Tim That's an interesting idea. I will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the failing user gets some AWS_... environment variables set and they then interfere with the instance credentials? I’m not a Windows person but surely there is a way to list all env vars. If something starting with AWS is set unset it and try again.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Probably not. There is nothing set for the userdata, group policy, users' profile, or anything.  The User that doesn't work, logs in the same way as the User that does work.  Very difficult to debug :/

Answer (score 0):

The AWS credentials usually come either from environment variables or from `$HOME/.aws/credentials` or from the instance metadata. Does `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials` exists for the second user by any chance?

According to this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html

for PowerShell the credentials can be also located at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit\RegisteredAccounts.json.`

AWS credentials are no magic. It is just an algorithm which looks up the credentials on several places in a well defined order. Either the second user cannot read the instance metadata URL or there must be a location with higher priority with stale credentials in it.